# Changing xml crashing my app

Tags: android, xml, chronometer

so my stopwatch class worked fine until I made some changes in XML code of it. Basiclly what I did is change some sizes and layout_margins..nothing special

heres the xml code, and logcat

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

         <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
             android:text="Chronometer"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="50dp"

            />


         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_sm_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"



            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_sm_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_sm_stop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
             />



       </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

heres the logcat

```
07-12 20:35:46.253: I/Process(360): Sending signal. PID: 360 SIG: 9
07-12 20:37:25.973: D/AndroidRuntime(395): Shutting down VM
07-12 20:37:25.973: W/dalvikvm(395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mioc.diver/mioc.diver.StopwatchMenu}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Chronometer
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Chronometer
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at mioc.diver.StopwatchMenu.Create(StopwatchMenu.java:30)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at mioc.diver.StopwatchMenu.onCreate(StopwatchMenu.java:23)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-12 20:37:25.993: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  ... 11 more
```

here's java code of this activity

```
 package mioc.diver;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Chronometer;

    public class StopwatchMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        int pause1 = 0;
        long stopped = 0;
        Button start;
        Button stop;
        Button pause;
        Chronometer stopwatch;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.stopwatch_menu);
            Create();


    }
        private void Create() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_sm_start);
            stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_sm_stop);
            pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_sm_pause);
            stopwatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

            start.setOnClickListener(this);
            stop.setOnClickListener(this);
            pause.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.bt_sm_start:
                if(pause1 == 0)
                stopwatch.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                //stopwatch.setBase(stopped);
            stopwatch.start();

            pause1 = 0;

                break;
            case R.id.bt_sm_pause:
                stopwatch.stop();
                stopped = 0;
                stopped = stopwatch.getBase();
                pause1 = 1;


                break;
            case R.id.bt_sm_stop:
                stopwatch.stop();
                stopwatch.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());




            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: post your activity code if you can!

Comment: Can you show an example of the relevant XML that you changed?

Comment: There is a problem on line no 30 of your StopwatchMenu.java. Post that line.

Comment: Basically i was playing with margins, and i put the chronometer inside his own linear layout...

Comment: what is line no 23 and line no 30 of your activity code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: ok, thank you very much, simple clean up was needed and it works as before...
can you just tell me, why this was needed?

Comment: You're welcome :-). From my experience it just seems like the ADT plugin doesn't always gracefully handle changes to xml resources. I don't know the specific reason why

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably `stopwatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);`

You're attempting to cast a `View` as a `Chronometer`. Your LogCat says that a `ClassCastException` was thrown, which means that casting `Views` as `Chronometer` probably isn't supported.

Alternately, something could be going wrong with the `stopwatch.setBase` method. You might be casting a `long` or `double` as an `int` or vice-versa. Look at your method parameters and returns to make sure you're matching up the proper parameter types.